# check how many objects are created java

Tags: java

so i need to create a class where it would have a constructor that stores value into a member variable, and a method that returns the absolute difference between an object's value and the average of all the initialized objects' values. so far i have written these

edit: how can i check how many objects have been initialized?

```
public class Value {
    static int count = 0;
    double value = 0;

    public Value(double value) {
        count += 1;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getDiffWithAvg() {
        double sum = 0;
        if (value != 0) {
            sum += value;
        }
        double average = sum / count;
        return (value - average);
    }
}
```

am i going in the right direction?

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you need help with specifically.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I was just wondering if there is a way to check how many objects have been initalized.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the sum must be `static` too, so you can increase it every time you create an object.

```
public Value(double value) {
    count += 1;
    this.value = value;
    sum += value;
}
```

Comment: good call, but is there a way for me to check how many objects have been initialized?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you are in the right way. It's good to use `static` for this.

Comment: is there a way to check when multiple objects are created though?

Comment: That can be also done with a counter static variable.

Comment: @Schuld your `count` variable tells you how many objects were created. Note that this is not usually something that people want to do, so I suspect it's not actually what *you* want to do either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to instantiate multiple objects of your Values class, in which case the code you provided is sufficient. The value of a static variable is shared between all instances of the class it is in, as opposed to non-static which is different for each. However, I do recommend setting your member variables as private and using public methods if you ever want to modify them. It's just good practice. Also make a static variable 'sum' and add the new value to each each time this class is instantiated.
Good Luck! :)

```
public class Value {
    private static int count = 0;
    private static double sum = 0;
    private double value = 0;

    public Value(double value) {
        count += 1;
        this.value = value;
        sum += value;
    }

    public double getDiffWithAvg() {
        double average = sum / count;
        return (value - average);
    }
}
```